# How can the absolute position change within a relative div (html/css)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I didn't know how else to phrase the question, but I'll try to explain through code

```
<ul>
 <li><span>1</span><li>
 <li><span>2</span><li>
 <li><span>3</span><li>
 <li><span>4</span><li>
</ul>

ul{ width:90px}
ul li{width:30px; float:left; position:relative;}
ul li:hover span{ position:absolute; width:60px;}
```

Now, when you hover on list one, its span would cover list 2, and list 2 would cover list 3. Once you hover over the third list, its span would run over the ul element. So is there a way to make the third span expand from right to left? So at the moment the spans starting point (as I understand it) is the top-left corner of the list. Is there a way to make it start from right. So the extra 30px expand to the left, not to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first,you closed the LI tag incorrectly.I execute the same code as yours.but when i hovered any span nothing happened and it is regular and correct.i think you mean something like jquery accordian plugin or something lick that.maybe you can do that with jquery instead of css in this issue.If you need its code comment me.good luck

Comment: my original code is too completed for me to have copied and pasted it, so I typed that in (hence the ending mistake) but that. to the above code you would need to add a background color to the ul li:hover in order to see the effect (I thought that was enough for demonstrating what I needed). i am going to try that plugin. Though is it possible without js

Comment: possibility or impossibility was not my concern.may you are right and you can do that with css ;-) . but surly it think jquery is better one solution in this issue.

Comment: i saw your posted link.hahaha.look at the jquery plugin.is that one better than this?Did you saw it`s movement? although it dose not exactly what you want.but it is a idea for you to to do your issue with jquery.use the accourdion that try to change it asthing you want.it is easy

Comment: yes I was thinking that plugin (as it is) does not do what I need. it would simply animate. as the drop-down can be done similar did it.

Comment: look at this component.may be you can change it to what do you need

Comment: which component are you talking about

Comment: i meant jquery accordian plugin

Comment: yes I will, by the way, do you know how can I apply a maring-left:-60px to an absolute div? as I just thought that would solve the problem, but is not working for me

Comment: I fixed what I neede with using a negative value for margin-left -  @ali ali thanks for you help